# Divorce Decree: Vacation Time

Tags: sentence, range-inclusion

"Vacation time is defined as not more than seven consecutive days, including the vacationing parent's parenting time weekend."

Does this mean that a parents vacation time must include their parenting weekend.if the vacation is only 6 days it doesn't need to fall on the vacationing parents weekend?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Legal language can have meanings different from their ordinary usage, so it would be best to consult an attorney in the relevant jurisdiction as opposed to asking an anonymous question to the Internet.

Comment: I agree, you should ask someone with expertise (your own lawyer or maybe someone at the court). However, I read it as meaning that you can't "tack on" an extra two days "parenting time weekend" to a 7-day vacation; presumably this language is for the non-custodial parent, and it basically means that person has to return the kid(s) to the custodial parent at the end of 7 days, not 8 or 9 even if there's a "parenting weekend" in there somewhere. But again, I am not a lawyer, and your best bet is to consult someone who is.

Comment: I agree with both choster and 1006a, in every respect.